# Code implementation in interface

Tags: java, interface, implementation

I've been wondering why it's allowed to do a code implementation in an interface, when interfaces are suppossed to contain no code implementation:

```
public interface someInterface{
String someString = "example";   
}
```

I can make a class implement this interface, without getting an error:

```
public class someClass implements someInterface
```

How come?

Comment: To add to your wonder, `Java 8` is on the way with *default* method implementation allowed.

Comment: @Ravinder really? At what point do we start calling them classes? I thought Java is supposed to be single inheritance...

Comment: @Cruncher You can read more at [Introduction to Default Methods (Defender Methods) in Java 8](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/introduction-to-default-methods-defender-methods-in-java-8.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are allowed to declare constants in interfaces, which is what you have done.  You have not implemented code.

Variables declared in interfaces are implicitly declared `public static final`.

The [JLS, Section 9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3), covers this:

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any
>   or all of these modifiers for such fields.

Comment: So I guess I've mixed up implementation and initialization. The string in the example is only a variable initialization, and not code implementation, right?

Comment: Correct, it's just initialization of a constant, not implementing any methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict condition that an interface must have signatured methods.Remember there are Marker Interfaces too  in java.

And secondly , You can declare variables inside interface.

And that variable `someString` assigned in a `static context`  and shared across all the `implemntations` by that `interface`

Point is that the variables inside declared `interface` are implicitly `static` and final.You can use them.

Answer (score 0):

According to [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

> Interfaces form a contract between the class and the outside world, and this contract is enforced at build time by the compiler. If your class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that interface must appear in its source code before the class will successfully compile.

Here you are not defined any methods to implement.So you didn't get any error here.